# PHP Any better way to write this if + ternary function?

Tags: php

Basically it just switches between the two values. If I input X I get 6, if I input 6 I get X. If I input anything else the value comes through unchanged.

```
function change($val) {
  if ($val == "X" || $val == 6) { $val = $val=="X" ? 6 : "X"; } else
  if ($val == "J" || $val == 3) { $val = $val=="J" ?  3 : "J"; }
  return $val;
}
```

This is a simplified version of the function I'm actually using so no need to ask why I need it. I tried it as and array but it doesn't work since I will input other numbers which need to output without changing. It needs to input all numbers and letters but only change ones in the function, others should go through untouched.

Expected output.

```
change(6)
X
change(8)
8
change(X)
6
change(L)
L
change(3)
J
```

I'm basically looking for a simpler way to write this function if there is one. It just looks ugly to me as it is but it's fine if there is no better way.

Editing to add an additional condition since I didn't realise that the code might be very different for one, or more than one condition. The actual code has five conditions you see.

Comment: You should use an array. In combination with `array_key_exists` and `in_array` you can do exactly what you need.

Comment: Is there any need to write something so condensed? What's the problem in writing a proper, simple, non-fancy condition and early escapes?

Comment: @Nico Haase not sure what you mean.

Comment: I agree with @NicoHaase. What would be the problem to write a simple if elseif else or switch statement?

Comment: @Felix You mean leave the code as it is?

Comment: From my POV, there is huge problem with such condensed logic: will you understand it six months from now? Will your collegues understand it after you've left the project? Will you be able to simply test such code, and simply refactor it if your requirements change?

Comment: @Nico Haase Yeah those are good points. So you mean write it all out really long with Ifs etc. Yes I normally don't understand my code 6 months down the line, I've only recently started commenting even. I just love short, concise code. The shorter I can write something the happier I am.

Comment: Don't want to be rude, don't take it personally, but that is bullsh.... if you struggle with understanding your code already, be more verbose when writing it. If you do it for fun projects, it's perfect to learn new techniques and play some code golf - if you want to do it professionally, better write good code than short code

Comment: @Nico Haase Yeah that's understandable but I don't do it professionally, just for my own projects. Otherwise I would certainly use commenting and more readable code. People do use ternary operators professionally too though.

Comment: Yes, they do - I don't want to argue against that, but from my POV, it's meant to be used in simple cases, and yours does not look like that

Comment: @Hasen What I mean is: Why not keep it as simple as possible like the answer from Xatenev?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this solution if you're using PHP >7.0:

```
function change($val)
{
    return [6 => 'X', 'X' => 6][$val] ?? $val;
}
```

For lower versions it could be like:

```
function change($val)
{
    $changes = [6 => 'X', 'X' => 6];

    return isset($changes[$val]) ? $changes[$val] : $val;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, you should maybe precise that it's version 7.0+

Comment: Double question marks? I didn't even know about that. The code for the lower versions is about as long as my original code though.

Comment: @Hasen yes, it is called [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: Oh I didn't realise it would be shorter with multiple conditions. What if you added another condition, for example J into 3 and vice versa.

Comment: The double question mark is like the 'or' in lua? Like v = 1 or 0. Funny that's kind of exactly what I was looking for but assumed PHP didn't have it.

Comment: @Hasen Its called the null coalesce operator and it works like that: `It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.` You can chain it more often though: https://3v4l.org/MIHW2

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operator:

```
// Return 6 if $val is 'X'
// Return 'X' if $val is 6
// Return same if $val is not 'X' and 6
function change($val) {
    return (($val == "X") ? 6 : ($val == 6 ? 'X' : $val));
}
```

Adding a new (3rd) condition in it:

```
// Return 6 if $val is 'X'
// Return 'X' if $val is 6
// Return 3 if $val is 'J'
// Return 'J' if $val is 3
// Return same if $val is not 'X' and 6
function change($val) {
    return ($val == "X") ? 6 : 
               ($val == 6 ? 'X' : 
                   ($val == 'J') ? 3 :
                       ($val == 3) ? 'J' : 
                           $val

           );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that will give the expected outputs I listed?

Comment: Yeah you're right it works fine, this is kind of what I  was going for, a slightly more concise version of my code.

Comment: Are these conditions fixed or will vary depending on another condition (run-time)? If these are static then I can change my answer but if they are dynamic then you need to tell me the actual logic you want to implement.

Comment: What would you do for multiple conditions? Like to add another line that also changes J to 3 and vice versa? They are fixed conditions. X always needs to change into 6 and vice versa. The numbers need to be numeric.

Comment: I just want to confirm like X will be changed to 6 or vice-versa and J will be changed with 3 or vice-versa... so are there any more conditions...?

Comment: Yeah there are more conditions but I can surely add in more myself, I just wanted to see how you would handle more than one since you've got it all on one return line at the minute. Ok I see your edit and it doesn't work that well with multiple conditions. My original code can easily have repeats of the one line to handle multiple conditions. I guess I should have given these details in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189511/discussion-between-d-coder-and-hasen).

Comment: Definitely, you should add all the pre-define conditions in your question to get the exact answer in one post as fast as possible.
Also, now i know what exactly you want to achieve then it will be better to have if {...} elseif {... } else { ... } statement or you can use a switch case...

Answer (score 1):

switch/case seems to be the most readable option for me:

https://3v4l.org/VD31E

```
<?php

function change($input) {
    switch($input) {
        case 'X':
            return 6;  
        case 6:
            return 'X';
        default: 
            return $input;
    }
}

var_dump(change(6));
var_dump(change('X'));
var_dump(change('something_else'));
```

**Output for 7.1.25 - 7.3.2**

> string(1) "X"
>
> int(6)
>
> string(14) "something_else"

---

If you don't like multiple return statements in a function you could aswell refactor it:

https://3v4l.org/V722p

```
<?php

function change($input) {
    $return = $input;
    switch($input) {
        case 'X':
            $return = 6; 
            break;
        case 6:
            $return = 'X';
            break;
    }
    
    return $return;
}

var_dump(change(6));
var_dump(change('X'));
var_dump(change('something_else'));
```

Comment: in the first example, you could omit the breaks as you return before them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use-case you should be able to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$string = str_replace([6, 'X'], ['X', 6]);
```

Comment: If you can't use this, the answer from @MateiMihai should do the trick.

Comment: `str_replace` will return always a string, which may not be the desired output.

Comment: @MateiMihai That's why i said "depending on the use-case"

Comment: Yes I should have clarified the number needs to be numeric.

Comment: @Hasen then the answer from Matei would be the way to go. But honestly there's nothing wrong with your code and in my humble opinion, better readable code for everyone beats saving a few characters of code.

Answer (score 0):

```php
function change($val) {
    return $val == 6 ? "X" : ($val == "X" ? 6 : $val);
}
```

Comment: @Hasen Added parantheses. Can you try again.

Comment: Yes it works now. I've edited my question to add another condition since I didn't realise the code may be different with multiple conditions.